How to get last email received date in Distribution list using powershell
Currently, I'm working on Powershell and I'm trying to retrieve last email received date using Get-Messagetrace cmdlet but it only returns datas of last 7 days.
I have tried searching an alternate to find the inactive distribution beyond the 7 days but i'm unable to find the alternate.
Suggest a solution if any one have previously worked on this or know about this.
